# Import data from Instagram to Power Bi

Tags: instagram, powerbi

Im quite new using Power Bi and i need to do some Social Media informs.
It is "easy" to import data from Facebook and Twitter, but i couldn't find any way to import from Instagram.
This is possible to do? I need a query?

Does anyone can help me?

Regards,
Lucas

Comment: What are you looking to import?

Comment: Alexis, tks for your reply! Im looking for basic things, as the number of likes per photo (just to start)...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Documentation for the api is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/. This gives you the all media with meta data (including likes and comments count) <instagram_business_account>/media?fields=caption,comments_count,id,is_comment_enabled,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink,shortcode,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username

Answer (score 1):

- You can download CSV files from the meta business suite and import them to power bi.
- Use the get data in power bi from web and add the API URL.
- Connect Instagram to Power bi using a third-party connector, which should be much easier being that most of them have a direct connection to instagram.

Answer (score 0):

You can use connectors from here : https://github.com/mbilling/pbiconnectors

The other way is to use endpoints of Instagram to connect with your sharepoint.